# Getting an image path using fromfile()

Tags: bitmap, c++-cli, fromfile

```
String^ path = "C:\Users\Abu Bakr\Pictures\Photoshop\Thumbnail for zactonia.png";
        Picture->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(path);
```

I am trying to make a slideshow program. This is my problem I cannot put the image inside the picture box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the '\':

```
String^ path = "C:\\Users\\Abu Bakr\\Pictures\Photoshop\\Thumbnail for zactonia.png";
        Picture->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(path);
```

Comment: Platform independent way is preferred.

Comment: @user3343541 Note that the person writing the answer missed one location. Do not just blindly copy-paste, you need to actually understand the answer.

Comment: @user3343541 Also, Windows have always supported forward slashes in paths, so you could try `String^ path = "C:/Users/Abu Bakr/Pictures/Photoshop/Thumbnail for zactonia.png";`